# monomac / Xamarin.Mac - derived NSTextField using NSTextViewDelegate

Tags: mono, monomac, xamarin, xamarin.mac

In objective-C, I can make my subclass of NSTextField conform to the the NSTextViewDelegate protocol - like so:

```
@interface PasswordField : NSTextField <NSTextViewDelegate>
```

How can I translate this idiom to C# / monomac?

I have tried subclassing NSTextViewDelegate:

```
private class TextViewDelegate : NSTextViewDelegate
{}
```

And assigning that to the delegate property of my NSTextField subclass:

```
public class PasswordField : NSTextField
{
    public PasswordField(NSCoder coder) : base(coder)
    {
        this.Delegate = new TextViewDelegate();
    }
}
```

However, obviously this does not work since the *Delegate* property of **NSTextField** is (correctly) typed as **NSTextFieldDelegate**.

```
Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `PasswordFieldControl.PasswordField.TextViewDelegate' to `MonoMac.AppKit.NSTextFieldDelegate' (CS0029)
```

So how to make this work as it does in objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

If you are fine with keeping the delegate separate, you can do this:

```
class TextViewDelegate : NSTextViewDelegate
{
    public override void TextDidChange (NSNotification notification)
    {
    }
}

public class PasswordField : NSTextField
{
    public PasswordField(NSCoder coder) : base(coder)
    {
        this.WeakDelegate = new TextViewDelegate();
    }
}
```

or, if you want to use the same PasswordField object:

```
public class PasswordField : NSTextField
{
    [Export("textDidChange:")]
    public void TextDidChange (NSNotification notification)
    {
    }

    public PasswordField(NSCoder coder) : base(coder)
    {
        this.WeakDelegate = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I stated that in my question. In Objective-C, it is possible for subclassed NSTextField to conform to the NSTextViewDelegate protocol. I want to know how to recreate that idiom in C#/MonoMac.

Comment: If you really want to do this, assign it to .WeakDelegate instead of .Delegate, though I recommend against that.  You will have to apply the [Export(...)] attribute to your delegate methods.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of the WeakDelegate property. I will give this a try next week and let you know how it works out.